# Whether it is good to do lot of functionality in the setState Callback?

Tags: reactjs, loops, dom, callback

I am trying to check and uncheck a checkbox based on other conditions in screen..

I am printing an element using `document.getElementById('foo')` this is returning null even my element is present in screen and in DOM.

Please help me to solve problem.

I am developing code in which after API is being fetched state variable need to be set and do other functionality based on the respective state variable.

Is it feasible to do most of the logic inside the call back of the setState to promote synchronus way of coding or any other concepts are present to do the same?

```
this.setState({
    filter:filterValue
},function(){
  // Most of the coding logic goes here
})
```

Please suggest a prominent way if it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Well you definitely shouldn't use `document.getElementById` since it's against reactive programming logic but it's hard to say where is a problem if you don't provide example code.

Try to implement checkbox in React way:

```
const CheckBoxComponent = (isChecked) => {
   return <CheckBox checked={isChecked ? true : false}/>
}
```

**then in your return:**

```
<CheckBoxComponent isChecked={yourFunctionWhereYouResolveWheneverIsOrNotChecked}/>
```

Another point is that you really won't to hold logic in setState callback. I guess you are a beginner. You should get better knowledge of functional programming. It's easier than handling state logic and mutation.

**Judjing from your question you want probably something like that:**

```
const yourAsyncCallToApi = async() => {
   await someApiCall()
   yourFunctionWhereYouResolveWheneverIsOrNotChecked() //it will be called as soon as u got data from api call
}

const yourFunctionWhereYouResolveWheneverIsOrNotChecked = () => {
// handle your conditions and return false or true based on them
}
```